# Редирект nginx кроме некоторых ссылок

Tags: nginx

```html
   location ~ ^/wp-admin/ {
  root /home/admin/web/site.com/public_html/wp-admin;
}

  location / {
    
        
    return 301 https://new_site.com$request_uri;
    }
```

Как сделать редирект  с помощью nginx при этом оставить доступ к /wp-admin и файлам проверки гугл
Пробывал так но редирект идет всеравно или на wp-admin показывает 404

Comment: Использовать location

Comment: что-то не выходит у меня. Добавил код

Comment: попробуйте не использовать регексп `location /wp-admin`